# Javascript return variables from each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, return-value

Looping through children elements using each.

```
var divHeights = [];  
$('#parent').children('div').each(function () {  
     divHeights.push(this.clientHeight);    
});  
alert(divHeights);  // fails
```

How can I return the `divHeights` variable?

I've tried
`var hts = ('#parent').children('div').each(function () { ...`
but obviously that won't work.

Comment: `divHeights` should contain them after the `.each` statement. So just use it afterwards.

Comment: `return divHeights;` after the loop.  What's not working about that?

Comment: where in your code are you failing to access `divHeights`?  When I run it, `divHeights` gets filled in as expected

Comment: You are already adding the heights to the array. You have access to all of the heights at that point.

Comment: updated to show variable access & where it fails

Comment: what do you mean by fails?

Comment: If `divHeights` is still an empty array after that... then your jQuery selectors or your html is to blame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in better way using [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) like:-

```
var divHeights = $('#parent').children('div').map(function () {
    return this.clientHeight || 0;
}).get();
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6qatkLyo/)

Answer (score 1):

The `divHeights` variable is available all the time. You can just assign it to a variable whenever you want:

```
var hts = divHeights;
```

This will just be another reference to the array, so you can do that any time after the array is created, even before you have put any values into it:

```
var divHeights = [];  
var hts = divHeights;
$('#parent').children('div').each(function () {  
  divHeights.push(this.clientHeight);    
});
```

You can of couse just use the variable `divHeights` instead of the variable `hts` when you want to use the result, or just use the variable `hts` instead of `divHeights` from start.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it into a function like this:

```
function getHeights() {
    return $('#parent div').map(function() {
        return this.clientHeight;
    });
}
```

Then you can just call the function wherever you like to get the array contents.